# Crop and Select Only the Detected Region from an Image in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, object-detection-api

I have used Tensorflow Object Detection API to detect hands from images. By using the provided sample code (object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) I have been able to draw bounding boxes on images. Is there any way to select only the detected region (which is inside a bounding box) and get it as an image?

For example,

#### Sample Input Image

[image]

#### Tensorflow Output

[image]

#### What I Want

[image]
[image]

Object detection API sample code can be found here. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Thamindu DJ... could you please tell me what model were you using yo predict hands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in the tutorial the variable `output_dict` can be used to achieve that. Notice all the variables passed into function `vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array`, they contain the boxes, scores, etc.

First you need to get the image shape as the box coordinates are in normalized form.

```
img_height, img_width, img_channel = image_np.shape
```

Then transform all the box coordinates to the absolute format

```
absolute_coord = []
THRESHOLD = 0.7 # adjust your threshold here
N = len(output_dict['detection_boxes'])
for i in range(N):
    if output_dict['score'][i] < THRESHOLD:
        continue
    box = output_dict['detection_boxes']
    ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = box
    x_up = int(xmin*img_width)
    y_up = int(ymin*img_height)
    x_down = int(xmax*img_width)
    y_down = int(ymax*img_height)
    absolute_coord.append((x_up,y_up,x_down,y_down))
```

Then you can use numpy slices to get the image area within the bounding box

```
bounding_box_img = []
for c in absolute_coord:
    bounding_box_img.append(image_np[c[1]:c[3], c[0]:c[2],:])
```

Then just save all the numpy arrays in `bounding_box_img` as images. When saving you might need to change the shape as the img is in shape [img_height, img_width, img_channel]. Also you can even filter out all detections with low confidence scores if you use the score array.

PS: i might have messed up with `img_height` and `img_width` but these should give you a starting point.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much. Can you kindly explain what are the elements in bounding_box_img. Because I can't recognize what elements to use since there are multiple arrays inside bounding_box_img. Also there are multiple other elements which might came from output_dict

Comment: Then where can I found scores for each bounding box to get the highest predicted values?

Comment: What I want to know is, by using the above mentioned method there are 100 bounding boxes(100 elements in bounding_box_img) in the bounding_box_img array. How can I detect one or two arrays with the highest scores

Comment: The scores are stored in `output_dict['detection_scores']`, it is also a numpy array, the length of this array is exactly the same as the length of `output_dict['detection_boxes']`. I've editted my answer to better fit your goal

Comment: Yeah. I tried with this earlier. But the problem is then it will filter out only the first two elements. First element gives an error when converting to an image. Second element is fine. But it refers to a faulty region. I'll add output as next answer for you to refer.