# Object Detection from Multiple Images: extract detected bounding boxes from MULTIPLE images

Tags: python, image, loops, tensorflow, object-detection

I am working with the Tensorflow object detection API and working on [this tutorial](https://github.com/tiangolo/tensorflow-models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb)

Everything works fine and I have trained my object detection model to identify driving licence's numbers and I also manage to crop the detected bounding box and save it as an image as shown below:

Detecting the label:

```
  image = Image.open(image_path)
  # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
  # result image with boxes and labels on it.
  image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
  # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
  image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
  # Actual detection.
  output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np_expanded, detection_graph)
  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=4)

  plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
  plt.imshow(image_np)
  plt.show()
```

[image]

Cropping the bounding box out and saving it [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204998/crop-and-select-only-the-detected-region-from-an-image-in-python):

```
absolute_coord = []
THRESHOLD = 0.5 # adjust your threshold here
N = len(output_dict['detection_boxes'])
for i in range(N):
    if output_dict['detection_scores'][i] < THRESHOLD:
        continue
    box = output_dict['detection_boxes'][i]
    ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = box

    ymin = int(ymin*img_height)
    ymax = int(ymax*img_height)
    xmin = int(xmin*img_width)
    xmax = int(xmax*img_width)
    absolute_coord.append((xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax))

bounding_box_img = []
for c in absolute_coord:
    bounding_box_img.append(image_np[c[1]:c[3], c[0]:c[2],:])
    plt.imshow(bounding_box_img[0])
    cv2.imwrite('crop1.jpeg', bounding_box_img[0])
plt.show()
```

[image]

My problem is cropping out bounding boxes for multiple images. As you can see, I have two images but only the bounding box from the last image is cropped.
The coordinates of the bounding box are stored in `output_dict['detection_scores']` but when I print it, it only shows the coordinates of the last image that was processed.
How can I change or what can I add to the code so that when I run the crop it displays the bounding boxes from all images and saves them as well?

My desired output is this:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: From what I can see, your top snippet operates on a single image, as does your second snippet. Where is the part that runs it across multiple images? 

`output_dict` gets overwritten in your first example, so you'd need to store the `output_dict` results for each image in an array.

Comment: @n00dle I have done what you said. Now len(output_dict) is 3 rather than one. The problem now is that all outputs are float32 numpy arrays and when trying to convert them to int it says that _list indices must be integers or slices, not str_ .